# Retornar un elemento con clases específicas en un grupo con Jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery

Tengo un set de etiquetas que usan la misma clase, pero, hay una que tiene la clase `active` (El servidor elige quien la tendrá). Necesito obtener ese selector que tenga el conjunto de clases `.lbl y .active` Hice algunas pruebas pero no lo consigo.

¿Qué me recomiendan?

PD. De ser posible no me gustaría hacer un forEach, luego utilizar hasClass y retornar el valor, me pregunto si habrá una solución más simple con sentencias para selectores

Agradecería que me anexen donde puedo encontrar más ejemplos como este.

```js
console.log( $('.lbl') );
//Esto me trae todas las etiquetas

console.log( $('.lbl .active') );
//Esto al parecer está buscando dentro de .lbl un elemento con la clase active y no me sirve

console.log( $('.lbl, .active') );
//Esto me trae todas las etiquetas y adicional las que tienen .active
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<label class="lbl">Label 1</label>
<label class="lbl active">Label 2</label>
<label class="lbl">Label 3</label>
<label class="lbl">Label 4</label>
<label class="lbl">Label 5</label>

<h5 class="active">¡Esto no!</h5>
```

Comment: Necesitas borrar el espacio entre `.lbl` y `.active`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Para obtener el/los elementos que tengan ambas clases, `.lbl` y `.active`, el [`selector`](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Learn/CSS/Introduction_to_CSS/Selectores) que necesitas es: `.lbl.active`

#### Demo:

```js
console.log( $('.lbl.active') );
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<label class="lbl">Label 1</label>
<label class="lbl active">Label 2</label>
<label class="lbl">Label 3</label>
<label class="lbl">Label 4</label>
<label class="lbl">Label 5</label>

<h5 class="active">¡Esto no!</h5>
```